# Running .py fin PowerShell (again)

Tags: python, powershell

Why is this happening? It won't accept C:\

```
Set-Location C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts\pyscripts
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> Set-Location c:\Python27\Tools\Scripts\pyscripts
File "<stdin>", line 1
Set-Location c:\Python27\Tools\Scripts\pyscripts
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Was unable to reproduce your problem, have you tried `cd`? Also, out of curiosity, did you need the `Set-Location` cmdlet for any particular reason over the more common `cd`?

Comment: @K.J.Phan Because `cd` is an *alias* for `Set-Location` cmdlet. Use `Get-Alias` to verify.

Comment: cd C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts\pyscripts gives the same invalid syntax error. I'm gonna use my Mac. Forget it.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when Powershell and Python are mixed. In this particular case, you are using a Powershell command in Python script or typing it into a Python interpreter. Python doesn't understand the  `Set-Location` command, so it complains.